# Electron: Log path of file selected from showOpenDialog box

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am making an electron app and I need to get the path of a file selected in the electron open dialog box. I intend to get the path in the main process and then send it to the renderer.

This is my current code:

```js
dialog.showOpenDialog(options, (filePaths) => {
    console.log(filePaths)
}
```

However when I select a file nothing is logged to the console? How can I log the path to the console?

Comment: In the doc I don't see a signature with a callback... Personally I use let myresult =  dialog.showOpenDialog(myoptionsObject);

Comment: what's your electron version? this syntax is valid only until 5-0-x

Answer (score 0):

The latest documentation shows that showOpenDialog returns a Promise.

To access the file path, check after it has been resolved as so:

```
    let path = dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openDirectory']
    }).then((obj) => {
        console.log(obj.filePaths);
    })
```